# Stored procedure failing on linked server table, despite it working in select query

Tags: sql-server

I've got a stored procedure on my server that extracts data from another server.

It's failing on a particular table each time saying "Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 1" "The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table."

I can both see the table in SSMS, and run a select statement on the table from my server.

Can anyone point me in the direction of what might be wrong with this particular table?

Comment: do you run the stored procedure using your own account the same way as you run the select statement ? If not, it may be the permission issue.

Comment: I do yes.  To make things a bit more odd, I just ran it again without changing anything and it worked fine.  I'm baffled.

Comment: @Matt maybe the table gets dropped and recreated and was off when you executed the query?

Comment: try to select stored procedure from linked server: SELECT * FROM linked_server.database.[sp_name], is it exists? If YES,I think account used for Linked Servers not being added to the security of the database trying to be accessed.